# SeleniumBase on MacOS vs Windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I've been developing with VSCode on my Mac and haven't run into any snags when working with `seleniumbase`. I then started working in VSCode in my Windows desktop and started running into issues. Two things:

- on my Mac, there aren't any ads on browser, but on Windows there are
- on Windows the DOM properly doesn't seem to be read properly... `assert-element` still works, but then `click` on that selector won't work (it works perfectly on my Mac)

I'm using the same `selenium` and `seleniumbase` versions, and the same Chrome versions on both machines.

I haven't added any adblocker or any other `options` to my driver. The code is exactly the same on both machines and I'm using the `undetected-driver` from `seleniumbase`.

Something that I did notice was if I perform a debug on my Windows machine and step through, the code does work. Maybe it's a timing issue on Windows vs my Mac?

Obviously I can continue working on my Mac, but now I'm concerned about portability. I could maybe containerize the program, but would rather not at the moment.

Thoughts on what the issue could be? Or what I should specifically look into? OS? The way things are configured on the machines?

Comment: Seeing some code would be helpful for debugging. Also, be sure you've upgrade to SeleniumBase `4.24.12` (or newer) for the UC Mode fixes: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/releases/tag/v4.24.12 (it was released a few hours ago).

Comment: Nice to see you here! I figured out the problem, but not sure how to address it. Essentially, on Windows the DOM is taking forever to fully load because a lot of requests are still being sent server side. I haven't made sense of these requests, yet... but could be that my IP on my Windows machine is getting throttled?

Comment: You could try `--guest` mode on Windows, and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I did `--guest` and `--adblock` and that worked!